what is the type of mouseMove?
I'm trying to create an event handler for the mouseMove event, but I can't figure out what the type of the event handler is supposed to be.
When I hover over onMouseMove, it says the type is MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>. But when I try using that type, I get the following error:
Type '(e: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void'.

So I tried using e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>, but then I get the error: Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic.
Can someone help me out here? What's the type of e supposed to be?
function Button() {
 function handleMouseMove(e: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <button onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
      // ...
    </button>
  )
}


Solved it by using e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
